# Cannot use the standalone subpreambles and have the same \newtheorem command in the main TeX and subfile

Tags: amsmath, theorems, standalone, newtheorem

I'm trying to write a LaTeX book, and when I use `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]` comment, a weird thing happened: When I put the command only in the main file, the main TeX works perfectly, but when I put this command in the subfiles, then I got an error like:

> LaTeX Error: Command \definition already defined.
>
> Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

Please help, I spent hours to search online and none of them helps in my case.

---

Update: This can be solved by removing the following command:

```
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
```

But it is not desirable, since the compile time is much longer when I try to write this in different chapters. So is there any way to solve this without removing the `standalone` functionality?

---

The `main.tex` is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics,fancyhdr,lastpage,color,framed,amsmath,ntheorem,amssymb,cool,textcomp,subfiles,datetime,url,float,cases,mathtools,mathrsfs,inputenc,geometry,siunitx,enumitem,import,subfig,chngcntr,tabularx,sidecap,hhline}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
%\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}}



\usepackage{eso-pic}


\geometry{a4paper,left=11mm,right=17mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm}

\renewcommand\labelitemi{---}

\providecommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\providecommand*\Diff[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d^#1}}
\providecommand*{\e}{\mathrm{e}}
\sisetup{parse-numbers = false}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\providecommand*{\myTagFormat}[2]{(\ref{#1})($#2$)}


\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}



%\title{Summary of Introducing the Stars}
\author{}
\date{}
% \usepackage{fontspec}
% \setmainfont{segoeuil.ttf}


\raggedbottom


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[scale=0.2,height=\paperheight]{cover}};
\centering
\vspace*{5cm}
\par\normalfont\fontsize{35}{35}\sffamily\selectfont
\textbf{SUMMARY OF INTRODUCING THE STARS}

\endgroup

\tableofcontents
\newpage


\import{chapters/}{"C1"} 
\newpage

\import{chapters/}{"C2"} 
\newpage


\end{document}
```

And my subfile `C1.tex` is

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics,fancyhdr,lastpage,color,framed,amsmath,ntheorem,amssymb,cool,textcomp,subfiles,datetime,url,float,cases,mathtools,mathrsfs,inputenc,geometry,siunitx,enumitem,import,subfig,chngcntr,tabularx,sidecap,hhline}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\geometry{a4paper,left=11mm,right=17mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm}

\renewcommand\labelitemi{---}

\providecommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\providecommand*\Diff[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d^#1}}
\providecommand*{\e}{\mathrm{e}}
\sisetup{parse-numbers = false}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\providecommand*{\myTagFormat}[2]{(\ref{#1})($#2$)}

\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}


\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
\newcounter{1.1}The luminosity $(L)$ is the total amount of energy radiated by a star overall wavelengths of electromagnetic radiation per second into space. The units of luminosity are Joules per second, or Watts.
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

My second subfile is

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics,fancyhdr,lastpage,color,framed,amsmath,ntheorem,amssymb,cool,textcomp,subfiles,datetime,url,float,cases,mathtools,mathrsfs,inputenc,geometry,siunitx,enumitem,import,subfig,chngcntr,tabularx,sidecap,hhline}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\geometry{a4paper,left=11mm,right=17mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm}

\renewcommand\labelitemi{---}

\providecommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\providecommand*\Diff[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d^#1}}
\providecommand*{\e}{\mathrm{e}}
\sisetup{parse-numbers = false}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\providecommand*{\myTagFormat}[2]{(\ref{#1})($#2$)}

\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Star Formation}

\begin{definition}
\newcounter{2.1}test
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Bernard he is not using the standalone class but the standalone package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I see now. I skimmed though the code before it was made readable. Thanks.

Comment: @Mensch thank you for making the visual change, have no idea how to do that before.

Comment: why are you using the subpreambles option for standalone? It is in no way easy to handle, as it means that all preambles are concatenated. Check the documentation of standalone.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I was trying to write this using the article class, then it gets too long so I change this to the book class, and I copy this from some template online, and its working fine until now, so I didn't really know what wrong with this before.

Comment: well subpreambles=true doesn't work well if two preambles contain the same  `\newXXX` thing. Better remove this option and  take care that all your documents have the same preamble.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh I remember why I did that, if I can split one big file into several standalone tex file, then when I'm writing individual chapters, I don't need to compile the whole thing, it save like 20 seconds each time I run it, but that's not a good idea, isn't it?

Comment: there is no problem to use standalone, but the option `subpreambles` is a problem, if you don't understand what is does.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, it works when I delete the subpreambles and all those stuff, but I think the individual runtime for each tex file is slower now, which is not very desirable. Anyways, I will try to look up documents for the subpreambles pack, thank you for your help.